# show and hide elements based on slider value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make an slider to show and hide elements when moving the slider bar (ui.value).

First I create the elements (checkboxes) using jquery:

```
var start = 1;

$(new Array(30)).each(function () {

    $('#showChck').prepend(
        $('<input/>', {type:"checkbox", name:"checkbox-" + start, id:"checkbox-" + start, class:"custom", style:"display:none;", title: "Cambiar los canales que tendrá la linea: " + start}),
        $('<label/>', {for: 'checkbox-' + start, id:"label-" + start, style:"display:none;"}).text(start)
    );

    start++;
});
```

Now I have 30 checkboxes and they are hidden. I'd like to show and hide them based on the slider value:

```
$("#slider").slider({
    min: 1,
    max: 30,
    value: 1,

    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#result" ).html( ui.value );

        var startx = 1;

        $(new Array(ui.value)).each(function () {
            // Get elements ID
            var checkbox = $("#checkbox-" + startx);
            var label = $("#label-" + startx);
            //var slider = $("#slider-" + startx);

            if (1 == 1) {
                if ($(checkbox).is(":checked")) {
                    //$(checkbox).attr("checked", false);
                    //slider.show();
                }
                checkbox.show();
                label.show();
            }
            else {
                if ($(checkbox).is(":checked")) {
                    //$(checkbox).attr("checked", false);
                    //slider.hide();
                }
                checkbox.hide();
                label.hide();
            }

            startx++;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I had no idea `$(new Array(30))` was a valid jQuery selector!

Comment: It actually works lol, instead of making an array...

Comment: I didn't know this either, and would suggest you to use the good ol' "for var i = 0" instead. Anyway, does your code simply refuse to work? Does it give any errors?

Comment: are you trying this?? http://jsfiddle.net/19601n1a/

Comment: @lucasnadalutti I don't understand what do you mean with ol' "for var i = 0" instead??

Comment: @Sushil Yes that's what I wanted, but I don't know where to put the ifs and the commented stuff, outside or inside?

Comment: no need to do that. just use $("input:checkbox").hide();          $('label').hide(); before u call the $(new Array(ui.value)).each(function() {. just use the same code that i've used. i've just added 2 lines to your code. it should work fine.

Comment: I just didn't understand why instead of using this crazy (new Array(30)).each you didn't create the hidden checkboxes using the conventional loop: for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) { code }

Comment: @Sushil So I don't need the $(new Array(ui.value)).each(function()? I can make what i need outside? I'm going to try thanks!

Comment: @lucasnadalutti Ah sorry, because I'm still a noob :P I'll use the for. Thanks! :)

Comment: you're welcome @ChazyChaz. u can still use the function.

Comment: Sorry again, can I do this to hide another element? var slider = $("#slider-" + ui.value);  and if ($("input:checkbox").is(":checked")) { slider.hide(); } This will be ouside the array function.

Comment: It's not working :( If I could access the variable startx from the array function... The checkboxes shows another slider each, but if i check a box and move the slider hiding that box the slider will still be visible... http://jsfiddle.net/19601n1a/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find it simpler :

- to nest the `<input>` elements inside the `<label>` elements. That way, you only need to show/hide the labels and their respective inputs will automatically show/hide in sympathy.
- to select the relevant labels to be shown/hidden by filtering a jQuery collection rather than looping explicitly. As the jQuery site says, "write less, do more".

The javascript will be something like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var N = 30,
        initVal = 5;

    for (var i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
        $('<label/>', {
            id: "label-" + i
        }).append($('<input/>', {
            type: "checkbox",
            name: "checkbox-" + i,
            class: "custom",
            title: "Cambiar los canales que tendrá la linea: " + i
        })).append(i).prependTo("#showChck");
    }

    $("#slider").slider({
        min: 0,
        max: N,
        value: initVal,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("#result").html(ui.value);
            $("#showChck label").show().filter(":lt(" + (N-ui.value) + ")").hide();
        }
    }).slider('option', 'slide')(null, { value: initVal });
});
```

The last line is jQuery UI's cumbersome syntax for triggering the 'slide' event for the initial value. If you don't need this feature, then delete it or just set `initVal` to 0.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6vkyh4kL/)**

Comment: Thanks! How can I add the commented stuff? I'll need to hide those elements as well if the checkbox is checked, but just the slider.show and hide, not need to uncheck.

Comment: I omitted the `checked` aspect as it's not clearly defined. There would be some interaction between the slider value and additional(?) elements according to the `checked` rule.

Comment: This is the extra code I need to get working to finish the form, but for some reason it's not working now: http://jsfiddle.net/6vkyh4kL/1/ When a checkbox is checked a slider will create/show, what I need the first slider to do is to hide that new slider if the checkbox is checked and to show it as well when the checkbox is shown.

Comment: Sorry, it's not working in jsfiddle.net, in my website it's working well, except for hide/show the created slider.

Comment: In the fiddle, `newSlider` is created but not inserted into the DOM.

Comment: Hmmm that's really odd, because it's a copy paste from the file and it's working right now.

Comment: Remember that I modified the HTML to wrap the `<label>` around the `<input>`. Therefore `$(this).next('label')` should now be `$(this).closest('label')`.

Comment: **[This](http://jsfiddle.net/6vkyh4kL/2/)** may not be exactly what you want but it it runs.

Comment: Well it's better optimized but the created slider is still shown when the checked checkbox is hidden by the first slider. I'm looking for something like $("label").show().filter(":lt(" + (N-ui.value) + ")").hide(); to hide and show the sliders.

Comment: This is exactly what i need: http://jsfiddle.net/6vkyh4kL/3/ But it's not working correctly :(

Comment: Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/6vkyh4kL/4/). Note: I simplified the way the checkboxes refer to their respective sliders - using jquery's `.data()`.